# MySQL Select SUM of Total Transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have two tables transaction and detailtransaction, the relation is 1 to N
, here's transaction Table

```
    +-----+----------+--------+---------------------+------------+-------------+---------+---
    | ID  | TransactionDate     | GrandTotal | DownPayment | Status   | DatePaid            |
    +-----+----------+--------+---------------------+------------+-------------+---------+---
    | 173 | 2018-01-03 22:05:00 |   26000.00 |    26000.00 | PAID OFF | 2018-01-03 21:05:52 |
    | 174 | 2018-01-01 22:06:00 |   26000.00 |        0.00 | PAID OFF | 2018-01-03 22:05:52 |
    | 175 | 2018-01-02 22:06:00 |   60000.00 |    10000.00 | - 50000  | 2018-01-03 21:06:55 |
    | 176 | 2018-01-03 22:08:00 |   90000.00 |    50000.00 | - 40000  | 2018-01-03 21:08:19 |
    | 178 | 2018-01-03 22:34:00 |   70000.00 |    70000.00 | PAID OFF | 2018-01-03 21:35:00 |
    | 179 | 2018-01-03 23:13:00 |   52000.00 |    52000.00 | PAID OFF | 2018-01-03 22:13:35 |
    +-----+----------+--------+---------------------+------------+-------------+---------+---
```

and here's transactiondetail table

```
    +----+---------------+-----------+---------------+--------+------+----------+----------+------------+
    | ID | TransactionID | ProductID | ServiceID     | UserID | Tax  | Discount | Quantity | PriceTotal |
    +----+---------------+-----------+---------------+--------+------+----------+----------+------------+
    |  1 |           173 |      NULL | SV031         |      7 | NULL |        0 |        0 |   26000.00 |
    |  2 |           174 |      NULL | SV032         |      7 | NULL |        0 |        0 |   26000.00 |
    |  3 |           175 |      NULL | SV033         |      7 | NULL |        0 |        0 |   60000.00 |
    |  4 |           176 |         8 | NULL          |      7 | NULL |        0 |        1 |   30000.00 |
    |  5 |           176 |      NULL | SV034         |      7 | NULL |        0 |        0 |   60000.00 |
    |  7 |           178 |         5 | NULL          |      7 | NULL |        0 |        1 |   70000.00 |
    |  8 |           179 |      NULL | SV036         |      7 | NULL |        0 |        0 |   26000.00 |
    |  9 |           179 |      NULL | SV037         |      7 | NULL |        0 |        0 |   26000.00 |
    +----+---------------+-----------+---------------+--------+------+----------+----------+------------+
```

There's 2 things can be made in 1 transaction, buy a product or a service. So there's a ServiceID and ProductID on TransactionDetail's.

```
 on ID 173, someone made transaction of service and paid off
 ID 174, someone made transaction 3 days ago and paid it today
 ID 175 transaction of service and put Downpayment of 10k
 ID 176 transaction of 1 product cost 30k and service cost 60k, downpayment is 50k (minus 40k)
 ID 178 buying some product cost 70k
 ID 179 2 service and paid off the transaction
```

The rule is product cant be paid later, only service can

I want to make a report of daily income, how to sum is based on the DatePaid, the result i should get is 26k + 26k + 10k + 50k + 70K + 52k = 230K

i've tried to get SUM by joining the table what i got is it repeating the value, like if theres 2 service in 1 transaction, it sums like its 2 transaction. here's what i tried, i got 336k

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'PAID OFF' THEN GrandTotal ELSE DownPayment END) FROM `transaction` a LEFT JOIN transactiondetail b ON a.ID = b.TransactionID WHERE DatePaid BETWEEN '2018-01-03 00:00:00' AND '2018-01-03 23:59:59'
```

Also how can I sum only transactiondetail with serviceID so that the product isnt the sum.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the total sum :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'PAID OFF' THEN GrandTotal ELSE DownPayment END) FROM `transaction`  WHERE DatePaid BETWEEN '2018-01-03 00:00:00' AND '2018-01-03 23:59:59'
```

removing products can by done by checking if product_id is not null and to get total use sub query as:

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM( SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'PAID OFF' THEN GrandTotal ELSE DownPayment END) AS total FROM `transaction` a LEFT JOIN transactiondetail b ON a.ID = b.TransactionID WHERE DatePaid BETWEEN '2018-01-03 00:00:00' AND '2018-01-03 23:59:59'  AND ProductID IS NULL GROUP BY a.ID ) as t
```

Comment: i've tried that too, but the result is row of total, how to made the exact sums of the row?

Comment: i got the error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if all you need is just the sum of amount, you don't need to join with transaction details. Just the below query will do.

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'PAID OFF' THEN GrandTotal ELSE DownPayment END) FROM `transaction` WHERE DatePaid BETWEEN '2018-01-03 00:00:00' AND '2018-01-03 23:59:59'

Secondly, what details do you need from transaction details table, do you want to see the amount by product and service grouped.